# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error while creating directory in FTP

Tags: c#-3.0, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to create a folder in ftp.but getting an error:

### **Exception:**

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." string

---

### **StackTrace**

at FTP1.Form1.d__58.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Downloads\FTP1\FTP1\Form1.cs:line 969\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at FTP1.Form1.d__56.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Downloads\FTP1\FTP1\Form1.cs:line 756" string

---

```
Error on below line:
**var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()**
```

Could you please help me to solve this? what's wrong in my code? I tried by using hardcoded values also.

```cs
**1.** 
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://URL/FTP/" + "NewDirectory");
 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
 using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 { Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

**2. Another One I tried:**
public static async Task<bool> CreateFTPDirectory(string directory){
try{
string ftpurl = sAppConfig.FTPURL1;
//create the directory
FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpurl + "/" + directory));
requestDir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.UserID, Settings.Password);
using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)requestDir.GetResponse()){
Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
ftpStream.Close();
response.Close();
return true;}
catch(WebException Ex){}
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. Have you stepped through this in the debugger? Does everything look as you expect it to?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, I checked while debugging. It looks as I expect. above is StackTrace

Comment: Please edit the complete stack trace (including type and message) into your question, instead of putting it as a comment. Ideally, isolate this into a console app to get a more useful stack trace.

Comment: Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and edit your question to make it as presentable as possible. Use the preview to check it before submitting - and ask yourself "If I were looking for a question to answer, is this appealing? Does it have all the useful information I might want, nicely presented?" (Hint: having to scroll horizontally because there's a lot of pointless whitespace at the start of lines doesn't appeal...)